# Keyboard and Mouse (possibly more) have power but dont work (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10

(Windows 10) My razer mouse (deathadder elite) and keyboard (blackwidow v2) stopped working after a startup.  It might be my other usb ports too but i have no input so i cant know for sure.  It has happened before but after a dozen startups and switching usb ports it resolved.  I have tried other mouses and keyboards but they do not work.  Is there a better way to attempt solving this or should i just keep restarting?

Comment: Does it work with other USB ports, maybe ports that are situated in other places (front, back etc)? Do the devices work on an another computer?

Answer (score 0):

Unplugging the power cable after shutting down fixed the problem (although i thought i had turned off my power strip before).  So all you need to do is unplug it from the wall and replug it